# checkbox images reset on browsers back button

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm using custom images for the appearance of checkboxes and hiding the real checkboxes. My form has 2 parts, so if I make a selection of checkboxes, then go to the next part/page of the form, then click the browsers back button, the hidden checkboxes are still selected, but the images/classes are reset so it appears that the checkboxes are not selected.

```
var $checkStyle    = $('<span class="check-style"></span>'),
    $product       = $('.productBox'),
    $checkBox      = $('#webform-client-form-18070 .form-checkbox');

    $checkBox.hide();
    $checkStyle.appendTo('.selectCheck');

    $product.click(function(){
        var $this        = $(this),
            $checkSingle = $this.find('.check-style'),
            $checkbox    = $this.find(':checkbox');

        $checkSingle.toggleClass('check-style-selected');
        $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

The .check-style-selected class is what shows the checked checkbox image. How do I keep that class on the element when the browsers back button is clicked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not:

```
$(":checkbox").each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked") { 
       $(this).addClass("checked")
   } else { $(this).addClass("unchecked") }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it does seem like better code, but the page is more complex than I stated, the code is not working at the moment, I'm trying to work it into the complexity of the page. Will let you know if successful or not.

Comment: $Rick you are welcome, I have styled ma website in this way, and this works for me, by using `change` you can simply updat custom checkboxes.

Comment: Ok, so just some feedback, I added the code to add a checked class or unchecked class if the checkboxes were checked or not. The reason why it was not working working after clicking the browsers back button was because the script was not re-executing. So I've wrapped it in a setTimout of 1 second and that is working now. It's the only solution I can think of at this stage.